# Looking up and Inputing arbitrary unicode characters in console/terminal

Tags: unicode

I'm looking for a simple, generic way to input arbitrary unicode characters in a text document on the terminal(e.g. in a terminal editor).
A basic method I can imagine is having a simple text(utf-8) file containing two columns, the character's name or description, and the character itself. Then I can have a simple script to lookup a character through this file, e.g. using dmenu or similar.

Are there similar methods available that would take care of this for me? Otherwise where can I find such mappings(names, utf-8 value) for common unicode characters(e.g. smileys, greek characters, mathematical symbols)?

This seems like such a basic common need yet I'm having difficulty finding simple solutions readily available.

Thanks!

Comment: A number of these specific subsets of Unicode can be addressed by enabling Compose Key functionality. For example "<Compose> g a" gets me "α"

Answer (score 5):

If using `screen` (`tmux` probably has similar capabilities), you could build a table of characters in:

```
 U+1F9D9 mage
 U+1F9DA fairy
 U+1F9DB vampire
 U+1F9DC merperson
 U+1F9DD elf
 U+1F9DE genie
 U+1F9DF zombie
 U+1F9E0 brain
```

format with something like:

```
perl -Mcharnames=full -C -e '
   for $i (0xa0 .. 0xd7ff, 0xe000 .. 0x10ffff) {
     printf "%c U+%04X %s\n", $i, $i, lc charnames::viacode $i
   }' | zstd > ~/.cache/all-chars.zst
```

and add:

```
altscreen on
bindkey \33u exec .!. sh -c "zstdcat ~/.cache/all-chars.zst|fzf|awk '{printf \"%s\",substr(\$0,1,1)}'"
```

(assuming a multibyte aware awk, so not mawk).

to your `~/.screenrc`.

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> within `screen` to bring up a `fzf` dialog to look the character up.

[image: Screencast of screen solution]

It doesn't work so well though when used within an application that uses the alternate screen which would be the case of most terminal text editors, as then `fzf` which also uses the alternate screen clobbers it and then switches away from it to the normal screen.

Instead of using `exec` which hijacks the current screen window, you could start `fzf` in a separate screen window and get the result `stuf`fed into the current one. You could even split the screen to show that `fzf` window in addition to the current one:

```
altscreen on
bindkey \33u eval 'split -v' focus "screen sh -c 'screen -X eval focus \"stuff $(zstdcat ~/.cache/all-chars.zst|fzf|sed s/.//2g)\" only'"
```

(`altscreen` not necessary in that case).

[image: screencast of solution using split screen]

If in a X11 environment (using a X11 terminal emulator), you could configure [`ibus-typing-booster`](https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/) as an alternative input method which [can also be configured to look-up Unicode characters by name](https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/docs/user/#7).

[image: Screencast using ibus-typing-booster]

Answer (score 0):

So I got to understand that I can get latest versions of Unicode Character Database here: https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/.
Then I thought about using python to generate such a mapping.

I can iterate through arbitrary codepoints and print their name(if they have one):

```py
import unicodedata as ucd
for n in range(0x0000, 0xffff):
    try:
        print(chr(n), ucd.name(chr(n)))
    except: pass
```

So this goes towards building lookup tables for codepoint ranges I'm interested in.